# startx gives black screen with nvidia drivers

Tags: nvidia, graphics, lubuntu, xorg, nvidia-prime

Some info:

```
distro: lubuntu 20.04
default dm - sddm
gpu - integrated intel, and Nvidia GTX 1650 mobile
nvidia drivers - nvidia-470
```

When I use the default display manager provided `sddm` the system works perfectly fine i.e `i3` `openbox` every wm works.

But as soon as I use `startx /usr/bin/i3` i get a black screen, i also created `.xinitrc` still same result. I also use another `wm` like `openbox`, i.e. `openbox-session` still same result.

I stopped `sddm` service and tried `startx` again still same result, i get black screen with no cursor. I switch to another `tty` and use `htop` and i can find that both `xorg` and `i3` are running.

I checked the xorg log and it reports no error.
`prime-select query` gives `nvidia` as result. If I use `prime-select intel` and then reboot the `startx` works. So I think I have to configure something when using `nvidia`.

How can I make `startx` work so I don't get a black screen ?

Thanks. *If I should add some more information please tell I will add it.*

`htop preview of sddm`

```
├─ /usr/bin/sddm
│  ├─ /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/sddm/sddm-helper --socket /tmp/sddm-auth1a548eff-e892-4543-89ec-705e1c6138a1 --id 1 --start i3 --user totoro
│  │  └─ i3
│  │     └─ /usr/bin/ssh-agent i3
│  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{36771d4e-9416-4be0-bfae-49c50dc60bc3} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
│  │  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{36771d4e-9416-4be0-bfae-49c50dc60bc3} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
│  │  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{36771d4e-9416-4be0-bfae-49c50dc60bc3} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
│  │  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{36771d4e-9416-4be0-bfae-49c50dc60bc3} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
│  │  ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{36771d4e-9416-4be0-bfae-49c50dc60bc3} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
│  │  └─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp -auth /var/run/sddm/{36771d4e-9416-4be0-bfae-49c50dc60bc3} -background none -noreset -displayfd 17 -seat seat0 vt1
│  └─ /usr/bin/sddm
```

`htop preview of startx`

```
├─ /bin/login -p --
│  └─ -zsh
│     └─ /bin/sh /usr/bin/startx
│        └─ xinit /home/totoro/.xinitrc -- /etc/X11/xinit/xserverrc :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
│           ├─ /usr/bin/openbox --startup /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openbox-autostart OPENBOX
│           └─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
│              ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
│              ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
│              ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
│              ├─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
│              └─ /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg -nolisten tcp :1 vt2 -keeptty -auth /tmp/serverauth.czCRUMFwtc
```

Comment: It looks like your problem lies in your i3 configuration, not your drivers. Have you tried starting `i3-session` instead of `i3`?

Comment: Thanks for the response, no there is no `i3-session` command, also I tried `openbox-session` it also didn't worked.

Answer (score 0):

Since I'm using `nvidia-prime`, I have to add some lines in the `.xinitrc` for it to work. The display manager `sddm` does it too but I don't know where it's script is.

Add these lines to starting of `.xinitrc`

```
xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
xrandr --auto
```

Source - [NVIDIA-Optimus ArchWiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/NVIDIA_Optimus)

Even better add some if,

```
DRIVER="$(prime-select query)"
if [ "$DRIVER" = 'nvidia' ]; then
    xrandr --setprovideroutputsource modesetting NVIDIA-0
    xrandr --auto
fi
```